# How can I create signature for AWS API in javascript using HmacSHA256?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a request to AWS API using Javascript, and starting with their examples provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html#rest_detailedexample)

I'm using [hmac-sha256.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC) library for that too.

Here is the code:

```
    var today = new Date();
    time = today.toISOString();
    time = encodeURIComponent(time);

    var messageToEncrypt ="GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\nService=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESS&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=0679722769&ResponseGroup=SalesRank&Version=2013-08-01&Timestamp="+time;

    var sig = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(messageToEncrypt, "MY SECRET KEY");

    var request = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=0679722769&ResponseGroup=SalesRank&Version=2013-08-01&Timestamp="+time+"&Signature="+sig;
```

I've used this library with the example which is provided in Amazon but I didn't get the same signature they provieded with dummy secrect access `1234567890`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using the same timestamp as the example? The timestamp is part of the message that gets signed; using a different one will naturally result in a different digest.

Comment: @duskwuff I used the same timestamp from the example but I didn't get the same signature that is given? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use the AWS SDK.  It's much simpler.

Comment: @Brad I want to make the request from Chrome extension so I need to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: @Mohammad Right, and there is the AWS JavaScript SDK that makes this very easy for you.

Comment: @Brad I'm kind of lost in their documentation, I would appreciate if you give me the URL of this SDK? Thanks

Comment: @Mohammad http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works now after I applied [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crypto-js/XMotofmultk)

I was converting `sig.toString()` to `base64` using a simple function, but using `enc-base64.js` library is converting `wordArray` to base64, I don't know what is the different really and I hope someone explain to me that :)

Here is a function I used:

```
function base64Encode(str) {
var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;
while (i < len) {
    c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
    if (i == len) {
        out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
        out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
        out += "==";
        break;
    }
    c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    if (i == len) {
        out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
        out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
        out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
        out += "=";
        break;
    }
    c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
    out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
}
return out;
}
```

Thanks.